# MonoTouch: UpPopoverController.DidDismiss not firing

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, uipopovercontroller

I have a **UIPopoverController** that has the **DidDismiss** wired up:

```
           popYear.PresentFromBarButtonItem(btnYear,UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any,true);

           popYear.DidDismiss += (sender, args) => {
              Console.WriteLine("Bye bye");
           };
```

The **DidDismiss** fires fine when the popover is closed by the user tapping **outside the popover**.

But, when the popover is closed **from with in the viewcontroller** that it is hosting, the **DidDismiss** does not fire:

```
        tbhCLose.Tapped+= () => {
           if(PopOver!=null)
             PopOver.Dismiss(false); //Won't cause DidDismiss to fire
        };
```

Comment: send true as parameter to popover.dismis(true)

Comment: Jep, that's odd. Apple tends to not fire the events in case the action is not animated. I do not understand the sense but that's how it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DidDismiss does not fire when popover.Dismiss is called.

Better option is to listen to the viewconvtroller's ViewDisappearing and do the updates there"

```
           var uc = new YearViewController(SelectedYear);
           uc.ViewDisappearing+= (sender, e) => {
              this.SelectedYear = uc.SelectedYear;
              Update();
           };
           popYear = new UIPopoverController(uc);
           uc.PopOver = popYear;
           popYear.PresentFromBarButtonItem(btnYear,UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any,true);
```